# What happens when OJ Mayo's two-year NBA ban expires?

Tags: basketball, nba, suspension

It has recently been brought to my attention that OJ Mayo would like to make a return to the NBA. I was just curious about what happens after his two-year ban expires. Would he return to play for the Milwaukee Bucks or enter the free-agency pool?

Answer (score 1):

**He will return to being a free-agent.**

He was dismissed from the league in 2016 after a drug violation, which also terminated his contract with the Milwaukee Bucks immediately. If he is to apply for reinstatement to the league, then he will have to be signed by a team as a free agent.

Comment: Note that the drug suspension did not terminate his contract, it was the reason the Bucks did.   The Bucks used it as a reason to void contract but there have been cases where teams don't and depending on how contract was worded either player is not paid during suspension or player resumes contract after suspension - example if 4 year deal and suspension after year 1 and a 2 year suspension, then after suspension still 3 years left.    The Bucks did not want him for that money so it was a business decision.   They had almost zero risk keeping his contract (angry fans).